# Verify user has the "Global Reader" role in Azure AD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I created an app that displays [SignInActivity](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/permissions-to-extract-signinactivity-from-ms-graph/m-p/2193636) pulled from a Microsoft Graph api query.
When running as a normal user it gives the error: `User is not in the allowed roles`.

To fix this error you need to give the user the "Global Reader" role within o365.

Questions:

- Is there an App security scope that will allow a user to view SignInActivity even if they don't have the "Global Reader" role?

  - The app already has the scope `AuditLog.Read.All`. This was needed to run the query.
- Is there a way to use Microsoft Graph api to verify a user has the "Global Reader" role?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the scopes through Microsoft Graph Api by decoding the access token, you can try to login into https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer with work or school accounts (Azure AD), you can just look inside the access token to see a list of permissions by decoding the access token into https://jwt.io/